# jsx highcharts performance

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am using the react jsx highcharts library to render a number of charts (20) on a single page using react.  My problem is that the charts take a long time to render and all seem to finish at once.  Does anyone know a work around or why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are probably rendering all of the charts at once (maybe they are all children of the same component). If that is the case, you could try waiting for each chart to finish loading before you move on to the next chart.

On the HighCharts website, each chart is created using a function that injects DOM elements into a particular `div`. Here is some example code for a component that uses an object with those functions keyed by their target div IDs.

```
const exampleChartBuilder = {
  lineChart: function () { var lineChart = ... },
  barChart: function () { var barChart = ... },
  ...
};

class ChartGallery extends Component {
  state = {
    mounted: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loader(0);
    this.setState({ mounted: true });
  }

  componentWillUnount() {
    this.setState({ mounted: false });
  }

  loader(n) {
    exampleChartBuilder[n](); // load the Nth chart 
    if (this.state.mounted && n < Object.keys(chartBuilder).length - 1) {
        this.loader(n + 1)
    };
  }

  render() {    
    const divNodes = _.map(Object.keys(exampleChartBuilder), key => <div id={key}); 

    return (
      <div>
        { divNodes }
      </div>);
  }
}
```

Note that if your chart-building functions are not synchronous then you will have to wait for async functions to complete before moving on to the next chart. Also if any of the charts or data need to change then I would recommend keeping the logic for each chart in its own component. But ultimately the same logic applies.